# Are there trivial zero free regions of the prime zeta function?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

If we let $P(s)=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}$ be the prime zeta function and $P^*(s)=\sum_{p^k}\frac{1}{p^{ks}}$ be the "prime power zeta function", then are there any known/trivial zero free regions of $P(s)$ or $P^*(s)$? In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302273/zeros-of-prime-zeta-function#:%7E:text=Let%20P(s)%3D%E2%88%91,%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01933420.) Math.SE question the answerer states that it is not known whether $P(s)$ has any zeros with $\Re(s)=1$. Since $1$ is not a prime numbe, neither $P(s)$ nor $P^*(s)$ have Dirichlet inverses and so $\frac{1}{P(s)}$ and $\frac{1}{P^*(s)}$ have no Dirichlet series and thus cannot be shown to not have poles for $\Re(s)>1$ in a trivial way like can be done for $\zeta(s)$.

I ask this question since I have found a reasonable route of attack for showing that $P^*(s)$ has no zeros for $\Re(s)>\sigma_0$ for some fixed $\sigma_0>1$, but I don't want to carry through with the whole proof if I am missing anything trivial. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: obviously there is a unique $x>0$ for which $1/2^x=\sum_{p \ge 3} 1/p^x$ as $f(x)=\sum_{p \ge 3} (2/p)^x$ is decreasing on $(1, \infty)$ so by the triangle inequality $P$ cannot have zeroes with $\Re s \ge x$ and same for $P^*$ and the appropriate $x$ for it

Comment: @Conrad thank you so much! The constant implied by this is $x\approx 1.757$. If I reduced this to something like $1.01$ would this be something worth publishing?

Comment: It's known that the prime power zeta function evaluates to $$P^*(s)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1\over p^{ks}}=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}{p^{-s}\over1-p^{-s}}$$. Hope this may give some help

Comment: I would add that the idea of @Conrad can be extended to the first several terms, and each additional term pushes the line a bit to the left. The limit of this process is to show that there are no zeros with $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$.